# How do I play mp3 audio(s) that is stored inside the java project?

Tags: java, audio

Most of the solutions tells me use the File Class, but I am planning to use the audio stored in the Java Project. If I make an .exe file, would that work when I'm using File Class?

Comment: Use [`Class#getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [`Class#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: You must not use File.  Do not under any circumstances attempt to create a File object using the string returned by the getFile() method of the URL returned by Class.getResource.  getFile() does not return a valid file name.  Do as MadProgrammer said and read a resource URL or resource stream directly.  For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaFX, there is [direct support for MP3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm). I just discovered this page, and haven't tried using it yet. I've always used `javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine` for audio output, and added libraries as needed to deal with the compression format. There are some useful libraries on github: https://github.com/pdudits/soundlibs. Of these, I've only used the jorbis library for ogg/vorbis encoded wav files. But the mp3 decoders here have been around for a long time, have been used in countless projects, and should work.

As far as packaging audio resources, a key thing to remember is that file systems don't "see into" jar files. So, a File address is basically useless as long as the resource is packed into a jar. But a URL can specify a file that is jarred. The usual practice is to have a "resource" folder for the project that can be specified by a relative address, and to load the resource using its URL. The URL can be obtained using the [.getResource method of Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)

For example, if you have a class named "AudioHandler" in your project in a package loction "com.dory.mymediaplayer", and a sub folder "/res", and an mp3 file "audiocue01.mp3" in /res, the line to obtain the URL for the mp3 file would be as follows:

```
URL url = AudioHandler.getClass().getResource("res/audiocue01.mp3");
```

However, depending on the needs of the library used for decoding the mp3, you might need to use the `.getResourceAsStream` method. The `getResourceAsStream` method returns an `InputStream` instead of a `URL`.